# (SQL Server /SSIS) Managing IS Catalog permissions on a shared server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm hoping for some ideas on how you and your team manage this. I'm supporting a shared SQL Server that will have several different departments deploying their SSIS packages via the IS Catalog. I would like users to be able to have some level of access to their packages, without that colliding with/seeing the packages from other groups. I envision users being able to:

- Go to 'Integration Services Catalogs' -> SSISDB -> And have read-only access to the folders containing the projects and environments they have deployed. Possibly full access to deploy new ISPAC to that folder, but only for folders they are granted permissions to.
- See the IS catalog execution reports for only their SSIS packages.
- Query the SSISDB database for only information (executions, package names, parameters) related to their packages.

How do you do this in a shared environment, where more granular permissions are needed?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add **Users** in the `msdb` database to the `db_ssisltduser` role as per the Microsoft Docs on [Integration Services Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/integration-services-roles-ssis-service?view=sql-server-ver15). Under the **Read and Write Actions** section for the `db_ssisltduser` role it says the following permissions will be applied:

> Enumerate own packages.
>
> Enumerate all packages.
>
> View own packages.
>
> Execute own packages.
>
> Export own packages.   Import packages.
>
> Delete own packages.
>
> Change own package roles.

You can also make a custom role that encompasses some of these permissions and/or other permissions as needed too.

Comment: According to the web page, this only applies for packages that are stored in the MSDB database.  Where packages are stored in the SSISDB databases it appears the options are limited to admin (which allows privilege escalation to sysadmin) or logreader.  The only other option appears to be to roll-your-own... ?